# listview lock column size winform

Tags: winforms, listview, locking, size

I want make listview columns non resizable.
Is there any property for column to lock its width? I don't want to implement this functionality with handling event because it is partial solution for this problem.

Answer (score 2):

It requires intercepting the message to change the size of the columns.  This can be done by derving your own ListView control that inherits from `ListView`.  See [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/myListViewNoSize.aspx) for a C# example.

As you describe, you can also resize it to a constant value by handling the `ColumnWidthChanged` event of the existing `ListView`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've already checked this link before. Is there any other solution if i don't want to derive ListView?

Comment: @Bandish Unfortunately, not (AFAIK).  Since you are essentially intercepting a message that the window is emitting, you have to fiddle with the API calls a bit.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to try a 3rd party component, [Better ListView](http://www.componentowl.com/better-listview) have **AllowResize**, **MinimumWidth** and **MaximumWidth** properties on columns, so that you can adjust individual columns simply by settings these properties.

There is also a freeware edition called [Better ListView Express](http://www.componentowl.com/better-listview-express).